# How to implement animation used by the little rectangle in XAML controls gallery app?

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp

[image: Little blue rectangle in idle state]

[image: Blue rectangle when moving from one row to another]

Animation is pretty simple! In idle state -- the highlighter rectangle sits in one of the selected rows. But as soon as another row is selected, the rectangle grows in length(almost like its made of elastic) and ends up in another row.

For detailed animation, check out the XAML control gallery app!

Comment: Do you want this animation in Hamburger menu or other places? If in Hamburger menu then check out [Navigation View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview)

Comment: Yeah I want the navigation in Hamburger menu but I also really want to know how it works, what I need to use to implement similar animation in other places?

Comment: You could try to edit the standard style via Blend. In the standardstyle you should be able to see the storyboards...

Answer (score 0):

The [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview) new control provides a collapsible navigation menu for top-level navigation in your app and it contain highlighter rectangle sits animation. Please note it only works in Windows 10 Fall Creators Update. You could use it to realize hamburg menu with highlight animation directly like following.

**Usage**

```
<NavigationView Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded" Margin="0,12,0,0" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
x:Name="nvSample"
IsSettingsVisible="{Binding ElementName=settingsCheck,Path=IsChecked}" IsTabStop="False"
Header="This is header text.">
<NavigationView.MenuItems>
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />
<NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Content="Menu Item2" Tag="SamplePage2" />
<NavigationViewItem Icon="Refresh" Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" />
</NavigationView.MenuItems>
<Frame x:Name="contentFrame">
</Frame>
</NavigationView>
```

For more you could refer [Navigation view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) official document.

I have found `SelectionIndicator` in the  `NavigationViewItem` stlye. You could find detail about `SelectionIndicator`. Unfortunately, The implementation of the animation is not in this style.

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationViewItemStyle1" TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="NavigationViewItem">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="40" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PointerStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="Red" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelected}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemBorderBrushSelectedPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Opacity" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PaneStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="NotClosedCompact" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ClosedCompact">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="RevealBorder.Width" Value="{Binding CompactPaneLength, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="IconStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconVisible" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="IconCollapsed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="IconBox.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    <Setter Target="IconColumn.Width" Value="16" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator" Fill="{ThemeResource NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}" Height="24" Opacity="0.0" Width="3" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="RevealBorder" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="IconColumn" Width="48" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox" Child="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Margin="16,12" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Update**

For `SelectionIndicator` animation, you could split it into multiple parts `Vertical translation`, `Height transformation` `Collapsed` `Scale` and `Visible`. So you could create a animation storyboard to describe both of them and bind the storyboard with different `VisualState`.

And @Vijay Nirmal also provide inspiration from [Continuity Tab](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity) that you could refer.

Comment: He is asking about the implementation of the animation.

Comment: Yep, I have checked the implementation  of `SelectionIndicator`,  but it does not exit in the style.

Comment: We can get inspiration from [Continuity Tab](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity)

Comment: The animation itself is handled via composition (you'll notice each selection indicator gets an added HandoutVisual in the live Visual Tree when it animates), but it can also be handled theoretically with a RenderTransform. Simply get the position of the next item, scale animate the current item to reach the next item, the flip (hide current item, show next item stretched to the previous item, then scale down). However, as it's done in composition it's not in the style nor easily adjustable.